# Why isn't my password being secured when using a custom user model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to build a custom user model in Django. My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('The given username must be set'))
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The given email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            username=username, email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff, is_active=False,
            is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
            date_joined=now, **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user=self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.is_active=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # Standard fields
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters'),
        validators=[
        validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), _('invalid'))
    ])
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    # Custom fields
    is_publisher = models.BooleanField(_('publisher status'), default=False)

    # User manager
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

Anyway, if I create a super user using the createsuperuser command, everything works fine : the user is created, and the password is hashed properly and secured. However, if I create a user from my admin panel, the user created has his/her password completely exposed. Also the confirm password field doesn't show up, which it does in the regular user model used in Django. How can I solve this problem?

Also, yes I do have AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User' in my settings.py.

Comment: You need to use a model admin class that takes care of hashing the password. See [the example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom ModelForm and ModelAdmin for creating/ updating User model items.

See: [Custom User Models with Admin Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin)

Answer (score 0):

`def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='user')
        upf = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofile')
        if uf.is_valid() * upf.is_valid():
           userform = uf.save(commit=False)
           userform.password = make_password(uf.cleaned_data['password'])
           userform.save() 
           messages.success(request,
                    'successful Registration',
                    extra_tags='safe')
    else:
        uf = UserForm(prefix='user')
    return render_to_response('base.html', 
                                               dict(userform=uf
                                                    ),
                                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

In your views.py try to use this and in forms.py try to get the password from django form. Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

A form with no custom code, and direct access to `password` field, writes directly on the password field. **No call is made to createuser or createsuperuser**, so set_password is never called (by default, a ModelForm calls `save` in the model when called `save` in it). Recall that writing the user password **does not write a secure password** (that's why `createuser` and `createsuperuser` call `set_password` somewhere). To do that, avoid writing directly on the field but, instead, calling:

```
myuserinstance.set_password('new pwd')
# not this:
# myuserinstance.password = 'new pwd'
```

So you must use custom logic in a custom form. [See the implementation for details; you will notice those forms have custom logic calling set_password and check_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py). BTW default UserAdmin in Django creates a user in TWO steps: user/password/password_confirm (such password creates), and then whole user data. There's a very custom implementation for that.